# requesting credentials with python

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way to request credentials like the PowerShell cmdlet `Get-Credential` in python?
I have been using tkinter but it dose not look as good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes using `pywin32cred`

```py
import win32cred

q = win32cred.CredUIPromptForCredentials("localhost")
```